# Use custom layout in Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have three row labels in my pivot table namely city, customer and customer_id. I want a custom layout so that when I expand city, customer opens up in the same row but when I open customer, Customer_id appears in the next column.

```
Col A        Column B
```

1. City
2. Customer     Customer ID

Comment: This isn't a programming question. (right-click the Customer field, choose field settings, and on the Layout tab, choose to show items in tabular form)

Comment: then all three go into tabular form. I just 2nd and third to go into tabular form

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Which version of Excel?